# Update table in Apache Spark / Databricks using multiple columns

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I'm trying to update a table based on a match to another table for multiple columns.  I've tried what is shown below but I'm getting the error shown.  How is this done?

```
update my_table set flag = '1' where (patient_id, org) in (
  select distinct (patient_id, org) from enc where lower(enc_type) like '%visit%'
)
```

Error:

```
Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: IN/EXISTS predicate sub-queries can only be used in Filter/Join and a few commands: 'DeltaUpdateTable [post_partum#1911], [1], named_struct
```

--- EDIT------------------------------

The following is a full example of updating a table based on a complex query that worked based upon the documentation given in the accepted answer.

```
MERGE INTO events eve
USING (
  select 
    enc.org as org,
    enc.person_id as person_id,
    min(encounter_date) as visit_day
  from 
    enc
    join events eve on enc.org = eve.org and enc.person_id = eve.person_id and eve.is_post_partum = 1
  where 
    lower(enc.enc_type) like '%visit%'
  group by 1, 2
) visits
ON eve.org = visits.org and eve.person_id = visits.person_id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET eve.delivery_date = visits.visit_day
;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, make sure you are using Delta Lake as the table format.  Second, I think you are looking for **Upserts**, which are [defined](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/upsert:%7E:text=Noun,updates%20them%20if%20they%20do.) as

*An operation that inserts rows into a database table if they do not already exist, or updates them if they do.*

To do so you'll need to use `MERGE` combined with `UPDATE`. Here's an example with the matching expression:

```
MERGE INTO events
USING updates
ON events.eventId = updates.eventId
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET events.data = updates.data
WHEN NOT MATCHED
  THEN INSERT (date, eventId, data) VALUES (date, eventId, data)
```

See more in the Databricks documentation [here](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-update.html#upsert-into-a-table-using-merge).

Comment: Thanks, I was able to do what I needed to based on the documentation link you provided.